# How to deal with a Cython ValueError

Tags: python, cython

I'm fairly new to Cython extension-types and puzzled with the following Cython-related ValueError that is thrown during runtime:

```
ValueError: vrptwms.node.Node has the wrong size, try recompiling
```

The Node class is defined in the files node.pxd and node.pyx in the directory vrptwms. The content of the former is

```
cdef class Node:
    """
    docstring
    """
    cdef public float x, y, demand
    cdef public float earliest_start, latest_start, servicetime
    cdef public int id
```

and that of the latter is (I temporarily removed all type declarations hoping to track down the issue)

```
cdef class Node:
    """
    Represents either a customer or the depot.
    """
    # pylint: disable-msg=C0103, R0913

    def __init__(self,
                id_,
                x,
                y,
                demand,
                earliest_start,
                latest_start,
                servicetime):
        """
        docstring
        """
        self.x = float(x)
        self.y = float(y)
        self.demand = float(demand)
        self.earliest_start = float(earliest_start)
        self.latest_start = float(latest_start)
        self.servicetime = float(servicetime)
        self.id = int(id_)

    # some internal functions
```

The node class is then included by a third file, problemreader.pyx, the following way:

```
from vrptwms.node cimport Node
from vrptwms.node import Node
```

The compilation works without any problem. setup.py contains

```
from distutils.core import setup
from distutils.extension import Extension
from Cython.Distutils import build_ext

ext_modules = [Extension("route", ["fastroute.pyx"]),
            Extension("node", ["node.pyx", "node.pxd"]),
            Extension("problemreader", ["problemreader.pyx"]),
            ]

setup(
cmdclass = {'build_ext': build_ext},
ext_modules = ext_modules,
)
```

I also attempted to add node.pxd to the problemreader extension without success. The issue is thrown at the following generated C code

```
  __pyx_ptype_7vrptwms_4node_Node = __Pyx_ImportType("vrptwms.node", "Node", sizeof(struct __pyx_obj_7vrptwms_4node_Node), 1); if (unlikely(!__pyx_ptype_7vrptwms_4node_Node)) {__pyx_filename = __pyx_f[2]; __pyx_lineno = 9; __pyx_clineno = __LINE__; goto __pyx_L1_error;}
```

and causes

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./cli.py", line 16, in <module>
    from vrptwms.problemreader import ProblemReader
  File "node.pxd", line 9, in init problemreader (problemreader.c:4991)
    cdef class Node:
ValueError: vrptwms.node.Node has the wrong size, try recompiling
```

I removed all generated .c, .so and .o files multiple times, but couldn't get rid of the problem. Any hints (including any links to documentation that I might have missed) are greatly appreciated.

Edit: the problem does not reproduce if I use old style relative imports (eg import node instead of vrptwms.node) and remove the **init**.py file - so there's nothing wrong with the source itself. I've created a tiny testcase reproducing the problem: [c_test.tar.gz](http://www.senarclens.eu/~gerald/tc/c_test.tar.gz) (needs to be extracted to a directory on the PYTHONPATH) and an almost identical case without the use of a package that doesn't reproduce it: [c_test_w.tar.gz](http://www.senarclens.eu/~gerald/tc/c_test_w.tar.gz).

Comment: I have a rather big TC not reproducing this and still cannot get the Error out of the original code. Once I have a solution, I'll post it here. Until then, any hints are welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Robert Bradshaw proposed a few hints on the [cython-users](https://groups.google.com/forum/?hl=en#!topic/cython-users/cOAVM0whJkY) mailing-list. The bottom line is that manually (re-)compiling the .pyx files with `cython *.pyx` and the running the original setup script works. There is also a newer way of writing the setup script described in [CEP 201 - Distutils Preprocessing](http://wiki.cython.org/enhancements/distutils_preprocessing) that should help but doesn't work in my current setup with Cython 0.14.1.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand what you're doing here:

```
from vrptwms.node cimport Node
from vrptwms.node import Node
```

When you importing twice to the same name the second import with override the first.

Comment: It feels weird to me too, but I followed this user-guide that tells to do just that: http://docs.cython.org/src/userguide/sharing_declarations.html